# Android move up LinearLayout

Tags: android

I need that my LinearLayout move to up when the keyboard is shown, I put this in my manifest:

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"**

The layout moved to up when keyboard is shown, but I have two buttons under EditText, the buttons are hidden under the keyboard. What I need to do to keyboard move  this buttons to up too?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap your LinearLayout in a [CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) and add behaviour of keyboard appearance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "adjustResize". This resizes the layout to fit the contents and not just pan to the EditText.

Comment: Hello, So I dont want resize, I want move the layout to up.